# Bash returns the error "failed to open vchiq instance" with pi camera and PHP

Tags: php, bash, raspberry-pi

I have a PHP code which executes a bash script. However, when executed, it returns the error, "Failed to open vchiq instance."

**PHP**

```
$message=shell_exec("bash /usr/share/wordpress/scripts/take_photo.sh 2>&1");
 print_r($message);
```

**BASH**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Testscript run succesful"
raspistill -o image.jpg -rot 90 -hf
```

I think that it has to do with allowing the www-data user to access the video, but I'm not clear if this is the case. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: it seems duplicated with  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19436/how-can-i-permanently-fix-dev-vchiq-permission-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was as suspected. I added the www-data user to the video group and rebooted my computer.

```
sudo usermod -a -G video timepi
```